# Не срабатывает REGEXP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, валидация, java

Проверяю введенный номер телефона на валидность (начинается с +, а дальше цифры, при этом первые 2 определенных значений) в [сервисе](http://regexpr.ru/),  все работает. Вставляю в код - не работает (возвращает false). Что может быть?

```
private boolean phoneIsValid(String text) {
    //text = +79312223344
    final String PHONE_REGEXP = "/^\\+?(?:79|73|74|78|77)[0-9]{9}/";
    return Pattern.compile(PHONE_REGEXP).matcher(text).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наконец-то нашел решение. Вот что бывает, когда редко сталкиваешься с темой.

```
final String PHONE_REGEXP = "^\\+?(?:79|73|74|78|77)[0-9]{9}";
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Juggler](/users/10616/juggler) - замените на `"^\\+?(?:7[93487])\d{9}"`